# Resize parent to match its child

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout, viewgroup

I have a complex xml layout with part of it being:

```
...

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flexible_imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

...
```

The height of the `FrameLayout @+id/parent` must be determined at runtime because it is displayed above many other views, and they must be shown in the layout. This way the FrameLayout fills the remaining space perfectly (using height="0dp" and weight="1" properties).

The `ImageView @+id/flexible_imageview` receives an image from the network, and it always shows with the correct aspect ratio. This part is already ok as well. This View is the largest and should determine the size of the `FrameLayout @+id/parent`.

The problem is that when the image is drawn, the width of the `FrameLayout @+id/parent` is not adjusted to wrap and be the `ImageView @+id/flexible_imageview` as it should be.

Any help is appreciated.

### -- update --

I've updated the layout to clarify some of the missing parts, and to add the reasoning behind all of it.

What I want is to have an Image (`ImageView @+id/flexible_imageview`) with unknown dimensions to have, on top of it, a gradient and some text on top of the gradient. I can't set the `FrameLayout @+id/parent` dimensions to both `wrap_content` because there is more Views after this Image that must be shown. If there's not enough space in the layout, the Image (`ImageView @+id/flexible_imageview`) is reduced until it all fits in the layout, but it should maintain its aspect ratio, and the gradient/texts on top of it.

The @drawable/gradient is just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#aa000000"
        android:startColor="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

### -- update 2 --

I added two images below to demonstrate what's happening, and what should happen:

Bug: [image: Bug]

Correct: [image: Correct]

Comment: adjustViewBounds does not influence the match_parent dimension of an image view. When you reduce the height manually, the image is being resized when drawing by the default scaleType (FIT_CENTER), but the view is still the same width

Comment: I'm sorry but it is unclear to me what you mean by "on top of it". Do you mean "layered on top" (like in z-order) or "towards the top of the screen" (like in y-coordinates)?

Comment: @FunkTheMonk the adjustViewBounds is used to keep the aspect ratio of the image, isn't it? I guess it is not necessary in this case, though.

Comment: @MikeT I'm sorry about that; english isn't my main language. What i meant was layered on top, like in z-axis. :)

Answer (score 0):

If would help if you explained more about what you are trying to accomplish in your layout (not the layout itself but what should the user see on the screen and what are the other elements in the layout).

A FrameLayout with multiple children is usually a "code smell". Usually, FrameLayouts should have only one child element. So this makes me wonder whether there is something wrong with your design.

-- Edit --

If I understand correctly, you are trying the framelayout to wrap the content of the image but at the same time match the space left from the other layout views before/after the frame layout.

What is the parent view/layout of the frame layout?

I see a couple of problems with this design or your explanation:

1. You have framelayout width set to match parent, but you want to wrap the content of the image.
2. You want the imageView to be reduced but you are not taking into account the text views in the linear layout. You have them set to wrap content. So when the fame layout is small, you will not see all the textviews. (Unless you are resizing them as well somehow).

Sorry if this isn't helpful enough but it's difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish with this layout. A sample use-case would help in providing you a better recommendation.

Comment: Hi Mike. I added more information about the reasoning behind my question. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Hello Mike. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I've attached 2 examples of what's happening and how it should be. Please let me know what more I need to explain or paste from my source.

Comment: You can't keep the aspect ratio and match the size of the parent at the same time without some type of cropping. Have you tried removing the adjustViewBounds and setting scaleType?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing adjustViewBounds and setting scaleType="centerInside" and it didn't changed anything in the layout (the result is the same).

Comment: Let me test something and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

When a dimension (width / height) is `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` adjustViewBounds will not effect it.

In your case, having `android:width="match_parent"` ensures that the image view is the size of the parent, regardless of adjustViewBounds.

It works to begin with because the height is `wrap_content` - the height is adjusted when the image is scaled to fill the width.

When you override the height to fit everything on the screen (this may not be a great idea to begin with), the width is still matching the parent and doesn't get adjusted. However, because the scale type is `ScaleType.FIT_CENTER` the image is scaled and positioned so that the entirety of it fits in the bounds of the `ImageView` (and centred.. hence the name).

If you turn on the debug option for drawing layout bounds, or look at your app using hierarchyviewer, you'll see that the image view is still matching the width of its parent.

There are a couple of ways you could do what you want.
Since you're already manually calculating the height, setting the width shouldn't be that hard.

```
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
if (drawable != null && drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() > 0 && drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() > 0) {
    int height = // however you calculate it
    int width = height / (getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth());
}
```

You might also get away with

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flexible_imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:minWidth="9999dp" />
```

Even if this works, you probably wouldn't be able to use it in a horizontal LinearLayout using weights any more (for example, if you wanted a landscape variant of the layout), or a number of other scenarios.